# reload canvas createjs/easeljs animation with ajax load causes layering or display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas, createjs

I have a canvas animation that has been created with createjs. The entire animation script including init() function is loaded via jquery: $.getScript() on page load.

The init() and handlecomplete() function included below is then run which attaches the animation to a html canvas element on the page.

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, audio;
var tweens = [];

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  images = images||{};

  if (stage) {
    stage.enableDOMEvents(false);
    stage.removeAllChildren();
    createjs.Ticker.removeAllEventListeners()
    stage.enableDOMEvents(true);
  }
  if (audio ) {
        audio.stop();
  }
  removeTweens();
  exportRoot = null;
  audio = null;
  stage = null;


  var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
  loader.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
  loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
  loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
  loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);

}

function handleComplete() {

  exportRoot = new lib.animation2();
  stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);   
  stage.addChild(exportRoot);
  stage.update();

  stage.canvas.width = 1280;
  stage.canvas.height = 720;
  resizeToFit();
  stage.update();

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", updateTimer);

  if (lib.properties.audiovolume) {
    audio = createjs.Sound.play("audio", createjs.Sound.INTERRUPT_EARLY, 0, 0, -1, lib.properties.audiovolume);
  }
  exportRoot.gotoAndPlay(startFrame );
}
```

My issue is when the user makes a change, we load the script a second time using the same jquery method which returns the updated script. The init() function then executes properly and the new animation plays correctly, but our animated text (using the animateText below) does not appear on the canvas. This function is also loaded dynamically with other functions.

Checking the tween arrays, they are being created and removed as required, but they are not visible.

They are either layered behind the new animation, or not being attached to the new canvas or something else?

Simply refreshing the page will then load the new script and text properly. So clearly something in the dynamic loading of the script?

```
var animateText = function(localString, startX, startY, letterClip, endObject, font, color) {
  var waitAmount = 0;
  var offSetAmount = 20;

  for(var i = 0; i < localString.length; i++){
    var fl_MyInstance = new letterClip();
    fl_MyInstance.localName.text = localString[i];
    if(font != null){
        fl_MyInstance.localName.font = font;
    }
    if(color != null){
        fl_MyInstance.localName.color = color;
    }
    var localX = startX;
    var localY = startY;

    fl_MyInstance.x = startX + offSetAmount;
    var beginX = startX + offSetAmount
    offSetAmount = offSetAmount - 4
    fl_MyInstance.y = startY;
    fl_MyInstance.alpha = 0;
    fl_MyInstance.scaleX = 0.1;
    fl_MyInstance.scaleY = 0.1;
    var bounds = fl_MyInstance.getBounds();
    startX += bounds.width + 0;

    var target = fl_MyInstance;
    var tween = createjs.Tween.get(target, {
        loop: false
    }).wait(waitAmount)
    .to({
        x: localX,
        y: localY,
        alpha: 1,
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1
    }, 400, createjs.Ease.circOut);

    tween.waitAmount = waitAmount;
    if(endObject == null){
        tween.endObject = {
        x: localX,
        y: localY,
        alpha: 0,
        scaleX: 0.1,
        scaleY: 0.1
        }
    } else {
        tween.endObject = {
            x: localX - endObject.x,
            y: localY - endObject.y,
            alpha: endObject.alpha,
            scaleX: endObject.scaleX,
            scaleY: endObject.scaleY
        }
    }

    tween.targetClip = fl_MyInstance;
    tween.arrayIndex = tweens.length;
    tweens.push(tween);
    waitAmount += 20;

    stage.addChild(fl_MyInstance);
  }
}

var removeTweens = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i<tweens.length; i++){
    if(tweens[i] != null){
        var tween = tweens[i];
        stage.removeChild(tween.targetClip);
        tweens[tween.arrayIndex] = null;
    }
  }
}

var closeTweens = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i<tweens.length; i++){
    if(tweens[i] != null){
        var tween = tweens[i];
        createjs.Tween.get(tween.targetClip, {
            loop: false
        }).wait(tween.waitAmount).to(tween.endObject, 400, createjs.Ease.circOut).call(function(){
            stage.removeChild(tween.targetClip);
            tweens[tween.arrayIndex] = null;
        });
    }
  }
}

var finalTweens = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i<tweens.length; i++){
    if(tweens[i] != null){
        var tween = tweens[i];
        createjs.Tween.get(tween.targetClip, {
            loop: false
        }).to(tween.endObject, 400, createjs.Ease.circOut);
    }
  }
}
```

Since the rest of the animation works perfectly using this method of dynamic loading, I don't think it is something in the loading. But there must be something missing in animateText and reloading functions that causes the issue.